# Expo eas-cli iOS build failing

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, expo

I have created an app using React Native and am trying to create an iOS app store build through Expo's eas-cli.

When running `eas build --platform ios` the `Fastlane build failed with unknown error`

After checking the "Run Fastlane" section in the Expo build log, multiple errors are shown:

**Error 1:**

```
Resolving Swift Package Manager dependencies...
$ xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./AppName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName -configuration Release
▸ Command line invocation:
▸     /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -resolvePackageDependencies -workspace ./AppName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName -configuration Release
▸ resolved source packages:
$ xcodebuild -showBuildSettings -workspace ./AppName.xcworkspace -scheme AppName -configuration Release
Command timed out after 3 seconds on try 1 of 4, trying again with a 6 second timeout...
[stderr] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0BD9B0475CB3419D8B91ED1E` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
Detected provisioning profile mapping: {:"AppBundleID"=>"f6b9bcbf-e950-43e3-847c-058bdc2733f9"}
[stderr] `<PBXResourcesBuildPhase UUID=`13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A`>` attempted to initialize an object with an unknown UUID. `0BD9B0475CB3419D8B91ED1E` for attribute: `files`. This can be the result of a merge and the unknown UUID is being discarded.
```

I have tried to locate UUID `13B07F8E1A680F5B00A75B9A` in my code to no avail.
I have also since installed cocoapods with `sudo gem install cocoapods` which did not change the error log significantly.

**Error 2:**

```
❌  ld: could not reparse object file in bitcode bundle: 'Invalid bitcode version (Producer: '1205.0.22.11.0_0' Reader: '1200.0.32.29_0')', using libLTO version 'LLVM version 12.0.0, (clang-1200.0.32.29)' for architecture arm64


❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

⚠️  Pods/boost-for-react-native: iOS@8.0 deployment version mismatch, expected >= 9.0 <= 14.4.99
▸ ** ARCHIVE FAILED **
▸ The following build commands failed:
▸   Ld /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-grbndlkaumowtzhaeqkpzrsevhvm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/appname.app/appname normal
▸ (1 failure)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
The following build commands failed:
    Ld /Users/expo/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-grbndlkaumowtzhaeqkpzrsevhvm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/AppName/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/appname.app/appname normal
(1 failure)
Exit status: 65
```

Xcode is up to date at version 12.5.1.

All help is very much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `"image": "latest"` to the eas.json build profile allowed me to continue the build process.

Comment: where did you add that line? Within "production": {} or alongside?

Comment: Try putting it in production

Comment: works, thank you!

Comment: more info on what `"image": "latest"` does here: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/infrastructure/#configuring-build-environment

Comment: I'm having the following error: 
Error: eas.json is not valid [ValidationError: 
    "build.development.image" is not allowed. "build.preview.image" is 
    not allowed. "build.production.image" is not allowed]

Answer (score 4):

If you get a validation error, make sure to put it in "ios" object

```
 {
      "cli": {
        "version": ">= 0.48.2"
      },
      "build": {
        "development": {
          "ios": {"image": "latest"},
          "developmentClient": true,
          "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "preview": {
          "distribution": "internal"
        },
        "production": {
        }
      },
      "submit": {
        "production": {
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things to look into.
If you are running Expo in the SDK then no need for cocoa pods just the most up-to-date version of the CLI tool.

Run `expo --version` to determine what version you are currently working with. Update if needed.

Adding a profile might be useful too. Along with checking your config.
[Configuring EAS Build with eas.json](https://docs.expo.dev/build/eas-json/)

`eas build --platform ios --profile distribution`

Also, be sure that all the apple certificates are active and connected to your Expo account for that project.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to some of the other comments, I actually got it to work after running these commands in order:

```
-    npm install -g expo-cli
-    npm install react-native
-    rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData\n
-    rm -rf node_modules
-    rm package-lock.json
-    npm install
-    npx react-native start --reset-cache
-    eas build -p iOS
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

be sure you're using the latest eas-cli

```
npm install -g eas-cli
```

should fix the issue